# Why does the vc++ 2019 not accept the code?

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer, constexpr, c++20

```
template<int N>
void f()
{
    constexpr int n = 9;
    ++*const_cast<int*>(&n); // ok
    ++*const_cast<int*>(&N); // error C2101: '&' on constant
}

int main()
{
    f<8>();
}
```

According to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category):

> the name of a variable, a function, a **template parameter object** (since
>   C++20), or a data member, regardless of type, such as std::cin or
>   std::endl. Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the
>   expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression;

Two questions:

**1. Why does vc++ 2019 (with /std:c++latest) not accept the code?**

**2. Why does C++20 permit a template parameter object be an lvalue?**

Comment: What exactly is it supposed to take the address of? `N` isn't a variable.

Comment: Even if you can convince your compiler to take that address (I don't know off-hand whether it makes sense), incrementing a `const` value will trigger UB.

Comment: Also, if you want a standard-backed answer I suggest using the [tag:language-lawyer] tag.

Comment: perhaps `++*const_cast<int*>` part can be omitted for the sake of minimal example? or is it supposed to be relevant here?

Comment: Also from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter): *When the name of a non-type template parameter is used in an expression within the body of the class template, it is an unmodifiable prvalue unless its type was an lvalue reference type, or unless its type is a class type (since C++20).*. You can't take the address of a prvalue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*template parameter object* is a normative term, that refers only to template parameters that have a class type.

> **[temp.param/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#6)** (emphasis mine)
>
> ...An id-expression **naming a non-type template-parameter of class type T
>   denotes a static storage duration object of type const T, known as a
>   template parameter object**, whose value is that of the corresponding
>   template argument after it has been converted to the type of the
>   template-parameter. All such template parameters in the program of the
>   same type with the same value denote the same template parameter
>   object. [ Note: **If an id-expression names a non-type non-reference
>   template-parameter, then it is a prvalue if it has non-class type.
>   Otherwise, if it is of class type T, it is an lvalue and has type
>   const T ([expr.prim.id.unqual])**. — end note ]

Since `int` is not of a class type, *it's not* a template parameter object. We can consult the relevant section for the normative text on the value category here, which supports the note:

> **[expr.prim.id.unqual/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#2)**
>
> ... The expression is an lvalue if the entity is a function, variable,
>   structured binding ([dcl.struct.bind]), data member, or template
>   parameter object and a prvalue otherwise ...

Since we are not in the "template parameter object" case, we are dealing with a prvalue, and as such may not apply unary `&` to it, like any other prvalue.

Answer (score 2):

Template parameters get replaced by the corresponding values at compile time. So N is no variable, but more like a macro. In you example you call f<8>() so the line `++*const_cast<int*>(&N);` will become `++*const_cast<int*>(&8);`

And of course you can't take the address of 8.

Comment: That's apparently how the compiler implements it, but is at odds with the documentation OP quoted.